# Looking for Yellow Climbing Rose Names - Zone 4 Hardy - Original Root - Info & Recommendations Needed

Tags: roses

I am in Northern New York (USDA Zone 4) and trying to find a yellow climbing rose hardy in my zone with it's own (Non-Grafted) root. I've looked through many nursery and rose society websites and have had little to no luck.

I've come across a rose called 'Golden Glow' hybridized by Brownell in 1937 (there are other more recent varieties with the same name i think) but can't find much information about it. I've seen it listed as one of his sub-zero roses, but I don't think it is. I've also seen it's hardiness zones as 6+ and as 4+ - can anyone provide more info on this?

The other variety that seemed promising is 'Harrison's Yellow' which looks like it's zone 4 hardy but i'm not sure it' a climber. (I would like something to climb up the wooden panels around my porch).

Does anyone have any additional information about these varieties, or any other varieties they know of and can recommend?

Again thats:
Zone 4 hardy
Yellow
Climbing
Own (non-grafted) root.

Thanks!

Comment: Why non-grafted?

Comment: It can get very cold here and non-grafted plants tend to be more hardy & live longer and you don’t have to worry about the roots being rejected or putting out suckers.